# Broken Resources.resx after deleting unused image

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, background, resources

I am using an image for a background on a Win Form in my application. I needed a different background for another form but found after loaded it that it was too vibrant so I used GIMP to fade the image so that it's more of a watermark, imported the new image in, set it as the background and deleted the previous version. Now my first form that uses an image I never touched is giving me an error saying it can't find the image. I look in my resources folder and sure enough it's right there. The application still runs and shows the correct background but I want to fix whatever is causing this error. Can I re-generate the resx file somehow? Error: The type 'MaterialTracker.Properties.Resources' has no property named 'REI_Background'.

Comment: The `Resources` folder inside the Project directory structure is just a convenience repository. What's in there is not necessarily part of the Project's Resources (you can put there other *stuff*). You have to add a file to the Project's Resources to actually include it and use it.

Comment: I realize this, however the method I used was using the BackgroundImage property on the form and the import button to import it into the resources file. The problem is I deleted a different image from the Resources folder in the Solution Explorer and now it can't find ANY of the images I had imported into the project.

Comment: Open the Form's designer file, look for any code that sets the BackGroundImage, remove that code.

Answer (score 0):

Go into Resources.resx by right clicking and selecting View Code. Scroll down the code till you find the  tags surrounding the reference to the image and delete the tags and everything inside the tags. You may have to remove ALL images referenced this way. I'm not sure if it's necessary but I then also closed and reloaded Visual Studio and I could then freshly import images like before with the BackgroundImage property.